# Jenkins Script to receive and respond to JSON without scripts

Tags: api, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins (other than calling builds in the browser UI).  I have not created builds myself.  The version of Jenkins (from page bottom) is: `CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.73.32.0.1-fixed`

Note, the purpose of this post is needing to test the API more than write a job/build. This is on a client's system with limited access, I need to keep it simple.  I can't even write shell scripts on the server myself for example.

How would I make a Jenkins job that would receive a simple JSON name-value pair like

```
{"request": "Hello"}
```

and return JSON:

```
{"response": "World"}
```

Without references to external scripts?  `World` doesn't even have to be logically connected to `Hello`, just static.

i am looking for an option to "Call shell command" input, where i can just `echo '{"response": "World"}';`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked but only part solution.

1. Install Parameterized+Build plugin
   https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build
2. Add string variable:
   [image]

   [image]

Assuming you control on the sending side please validate the Json is OK before you send him.

4. You will have a variable name MyJson.
5. Call Python script or other other language in the build steps passing this variable.
6. Install EnjectVariable plugin and create using the script file with a key value (the key is MyJsonAnswer and the value will be your value).
7. Call again to the same job and get the same parameter and see his value.

You can get all the info required using:

```
build_page = requests.get("http://<JENKINS SERVER>:8080/job/Playground-2/api/json")
build_page_parsed = json.loads(build_page.text)
```